# Azure RTOS + NetX Webserver Webpage Renderer

Tags: c, stm32, azure-rtos

I managed to successfully incorporate a webserver into our project with the following details:

- STM32H753
- Azure RTOS + NetX
- 32Mb QSPI NOR flash (8Mb for webserver purpose, 8Mb for File system, some part will be for internal use)
- provision for SD card

What I can do so far:

1. Managed to display images from my file system on NOR flash
2. Managed to post an encrypted binary file for firmware updates
3. Show a basic web page with a select-send firmware file
4. Running on HTTP for now (later HTTPS)

These are all ok. I am at the point where I want to display web pages. What will be a good direction to achieve rendering web pages with probably 10 tabs (maybe similar to router setup and status)? Not sure if this is the correct forum for this. Apologies if not. I am a beginner in HTML. Rendering on my own is quite tedious because you have to consider member placement relative to screen size, tabs, text properties, etc.

- I read about HTML drag-and-drop editors and converting to HTML codes
- I saw this page [Use a html renderer in an embedded environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398650/use-a-html-renderer-in-an-embedded-environment)

Not sure if I can use a 3rd party rendering package that can be run on Windows given my project details above (Azure RTOS)

I read a lot of people saying that it might not be a good idea to run a webserver on ST MCU because web packages become bloated. Suggestion of using ST MPU instead. However, given the limitation of using STM32H7 with external NOR flash access, what will be a good approach moving forward? I know a question will be how complex the webpage is. It will be for a monitoring system with basic controls of outputs and status of inputs, probably pop-ups for alarms and warnings, display images, Bi-directional, dynamic data (I read bout AJAX)

Thanks.

passing in basic HTML codes